# Cordova iOS app not asking for camera permission when submitting with XCode 14.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a Cordova app that requests the user access to camera. This plugin is `barcodeScanner`. This app used to work perfectly when submitted with XCode 13 on Mac 11.5. I then bought a MacOS Ventura and installed XCode 14.3. No change in the iPhone device and no change in the iOS version of the iPhone. However, exactly the same app is not working anymore!

I just downloaded previous versions of my app from GitHub to test, submitted them to TestFlight and they do not work anymore. As the app version has not changed, I suspect the only thing that changed is my version of XCode. I have not even changed the message to be displayed to user when asking for camera permission. What exactly is the procedure to ask for camera permission on apps submitted with XCode 14? Note the app does not crash when I click on the button to open the camera: it simply does not open the camera and does not display the ask-for-permission message.

I noted that on my iPhone's Settings app --> My app, there's no "Camera" permission line even available. Hence I suspect the app has not "acknowledged" it should ask for this permission.

My info.plist file is below. I added the line "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" with the same message as before the XCode upgrade and no luck. I have read on other posts that it should work if I removed certain lines of the file, but still no luck.

My app still works on Android, no change at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: info.plist file]